# dcount function is showing error datatype mismatch

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

When running the code I get the following error:

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

I am trying to check if record exists in table **tblMain** with an autoIncrement field **Id**.

```
Dim myId as Long
Dim tableName as string

myId = 1145589
tableName = "Main"
```

Note: The above part is just to show what these variable types and worth are. they are not actually presented like this in my code.

```
If Not DCount("Id", "tbl" & tableName, "Id='" & myId & "'") = 1 Then
    Err.Raise 540, "This record does not exist."
End If
```

I tried running the following query, and it was fine:

```
SELECT Count(Id) FROM tblMain WHERE Id = 1145589
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Long shall not be quoted:

```
If Not DCount("*", "tbl" & tableName, "Id=" & myId & "") = 1 Then
    Err.Raise 540, "This record does not exist."
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You have single ticks around your myId variable, but it's numeric so you don't need them.

```
"Id='" & myId & "'"
```

should be

```
"Id=" & myId
```

Here is the complete updated code:

```
If Not DCount("Id", "tbl" & tableName, "Id=" & myId) = 1 Then
    Err.Raise 540, "This record does not exist."
End If
```